# Removing spaces (margins) on a web page

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a problem with my spacing. I have to `<p>`'s in my code, but there is a huge space between both I wanted to put them in a table in different `<tr>`s, but it would not work, so I put them both in the same `<tr>` and `<td>`, but the spacing is still here. Here are the code and photos (ignore the long talk about chamomil and tea) :

```
 <table style="border-style: none; margin:0 auto; white-space: pre-wrap;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="tisane" style="border-style: groove; border-radius: 6%; max-width: 308px; max-height: 358px;">
            <img src="images/30467-5-tea.png" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" alt="Tisane à la chamomille">
        </div>
      </td> 
      <td style="max-height: 40px;">
        <a href="Millepertuis.html"><img src="images/272222649004211.png" style="width: 200px; height: unset; right: 20px; top: 170px; padding: 20px; position: absolute;"></a>
        <a href="tisanes.html"><img src="images/272222649004211.png" style="width: 200px; height: unset; left: 20px; top: 170px; padding: 20px; position: absolute; transform: scaleX(-1);"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 40px; max-height: 40px;">
      <td style="max-height: 20px;">
        <p class="normaltext" style="text-align: center; padding: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 30px; border: 0px;">Tisane à la chamomille</p> 
          <p class="arial" style="width: 430px; white-space: pre-line; text-align: center; word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 18px; top: 0px; position: relative;">
            Depuis toujours, l'homme utilise la chamomille en la consommant pour ses vertus calmantes et digestives, et de nombreuses autres façons. Retrouvez toute cette puissance sous sa forme la plus savoureuse dans notre infusion faite uniquement des pétales les plus qualitatifs.
          </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
</table>
```

[image: html]

[[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `white-space: pre-wrap;` nearly everywhere but you want it to be normal in that area. I've added `white-space: normal;` and it is showing as expected (excluding your local images).

```html
<table style="border-style: none; margin:0 auto; white-space: pre-wrap;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="tisane" style="border-style: groove; border-radius: 6%; max-width: 308px; max-height: 358px;">
        <img src="images/30467-5-tea.png" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" alt="Tisane à la chamomille">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="max-height: 40px;">
      <a href="Millepertuis.html"><img src="images/272222649004211.png" style="width: 200px; height: unset; right: 20px; top: 170px; padding: 20px; position: absolute;"></a>
      <a href="tisanes.html"><img src="images/272222649004211.png" style="width: 200px; height: unset; left: 20px; top: 170px; padding: 20px; position: absolute; transform: scaleX(-1);"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 40px; max-height: 40px;">
    <td style="max-height: 20px; white-space: normal;">
      <p class="normaltext" style="text-align: center; padding: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 30px; border: 0px;">Tisane à la chamomille</p>
      <p class="arial" style="width: 430px; white-space: pre-line; text-align: center; word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 18px; top: 0px; position: relative;">
        Depuis toujours, l'homme utilise la chamomille en la consommant pour ses vertus calmantes et digestives, et de nombreuses autres façons. Retrouvez toute cette puissance sous sa forme la plus savoureuse dans notre infusion faite uniquement des pétales
        les plus qualitatifs.
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Also, inline-styles should be avoided as much possible.

Comment: @Sapinder Why ? I think they'revery practical ? I mean I don't know where else to store all that case-per-case CSS unless there's a way.

Comment: The most prominent reason is **specificity**. The second one is **readability**. And what do you mean by *case-per-case*?